# Cannot convert value of type '(Float) -> FormExpression' to expected argument type '(_) -> FormExpression'

Tags: swift, closures

```
indirect enum FormExpression {
   case float(Float)
   case reference(String,Int)
   case infix(FormExpression,String,FormExpression)
   case function(String,FormExpression)
}
extension FormExpression {
    static var floatParser:FormParser<FormExpression> {
        return { FormExpression.float($0) }<^>float
    }
 }

infix operator <^> : SequencePrecedence 
func <^><A,B>(lhs:@escaping(A)->B,rhs:FormParser<A>) -> FormParser<B> { 
    return rhs.map(lhs) 
}
```

This is my code to practice closure and functional Swift. Now it displays a

> error - 'Cannot convert value of type '(Float) -> FormExpression' to
>   expected argument type '(_) -> FormExpression''

. And I try several times, still do not know how to do.I hope someone can help solve it and explain why.Thanks

Comment: Where does the `<^>` operator come from? Are you using any 3rd party frameworks?

Comment: `infix operator <^> : SequencePrecedence
func <^><A,B>(lhs:@escaping(A)->B,rhs:FormParser<A>) -> FormParser<B> {
    return rhs.map(lhs)
}`

Comment: This is the address of the practice project：(https://github.com/objcio/functional-swift)  .And I modify some code `let float = digit.many1.map { Float(String($0))! }`

Comment: @MartinR,I added explanation

Comment: Thanks to the friends who had made suggestions before,the first time I asked, I did not understand the format of the question. This is my problem, I am sorry

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem, but it was a bit funny.

> I just modified the name of the 'float' object and changed the 'float' to a 'floater'. That's it.

The two differently named objects are essentially the same, but the other one is an error. , I now think that may be caused by naming conflicts in Swift, but I do not have the ability to find the real reason, friends who have interest and ability can try to find out why